# Scraping multiple data tags from HTML using beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am attempting to scrape HTML to create a dictionary that includes a pitchers name and his handed-ness.  The data-tags are buried--so far I've only been able to collect the pitchers name from the data set.  The HTML output (for each player) is as follows:

```
<div class="pitcher players">
<input name="import-data" type="hidden" value="%5B%7B%22slate_id%22%3A20190%2C%22type%22%3A%22classic%22%2C%22player_id%22%3A%2210893103%22%2C%22salary%22%3A%2211800%22%2C%22position%22%3A%22SP%22%2C%22fpts%22%3A14.96%7D%2C%7B%22slate_id%22%3A20192%2C%22type%22%3A%22classic%22%2C%22player_id%22%3A%2210894893%22%2C%22salary%22%3A%2211800%22%2C%22position%22%3A%22SP%22%2C%22fpts%22%3A14.96%7D%2C%7B%22slate_id%22%3A20193%2C%22type%22%3A%22classic%22%2C%22player_id%22%3A%2210895115%22%2C%22salary%22%3A%2211800%22%2C%22position%22%3A%22SP%22%2C%22fpts%22%3A14.96%7D%5D"/>
<a class="player-popup" data-url="https://rotogrinders.com/players/johnny-cueto-11193?site=draftkings" href="https://rotogrinders.com/players/johnny-cueto-11193">Johnny Cueto</a>
<span class="meta stats">
<span class="stats">
            R
        </span>
<span class="salary" data-role="salary" data-salary="$11.8K">
            $11.8K
        </span>
<span class="fpts" data-fpts="14.96" data-product="56" data-role="authorize" title="Projected Points">14.96</span>
```

I've tinkered and and coming up empty--I'm sure I'm overthinking this.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://rotogrinders.com/lineups/mlb?site=draftkings"

r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

players_confirmed = {}
results = [soup.find_all("div", {'class':'pitcher players'}]
```

What's the best way to loop through the results set for the more granular data tag information I need?

I need the text from the HTML beginning with , and handed-ness from the tag 
Optimally, I would have a dictionary with the following:

{Johnny Cueto : R, Player 2 : L, ...}

Comment: can you specify some sample output?

Comment: Thanks, noticed I hadn't added that.  I updated the question.  Sample output would be:  {Johnny Cueto : R, Player 2 : L, ...}

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://rotogrinders.com/lineups/mlb?site=draftkings"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
players_confirmed = {}
results = soup.find_all("div", {'class': 'pitcher players'})
dicti={}
for j in results:
    dicti[j.a.text]=j.select(".stats")[1].text.strip("\n").strip()
```

just use select or find function of the founded element,and you will be able to iterate